# Determine whether current user session is a managed package support user session?

Tags: apex, managed-package, debug

Salesforce only shows debug logs from managed packages if you're logged in via the appropriate "grant support access" feature from your licensing org's licensing console. That's okay so far...

My question however is, if it is possible to programatically determine (e.g. via Apex) if the current user's session is one of these support login sessions with access to the package's debug logs.

My goal is to create a page that shows advanced information to a support user which should otherwise not be accessible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there is no satisfying answer for your need.

Some time ago I did some research on session ids for other purposes:

- [Get a FIRST-CLASS SessionID for API Calls (looking for a clean way or alternative)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42403/get-a-first-class-sessionid-for-api-calls-looking-for-a-clean-way-or-alternativ?lq=1)
- [Different Session Ids in Different contexts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23277/different-session-ids-in-different-contexts/23278#23278)

Bottom-line: the results where quite disappointing and salesforce seems not be very open about backgrounds and there is a lag in documentation.

Maybe you could capture support logins by their profile, username or permissions. If you had a chance to go in a go2meeting session with the support or write some apex so that a support user will trigger it while dealing with a case, you could capture some dumps and reverse engineer on it.

**Update**:

Sorry I missread it's your own managed package. Then you might be able dump some user information in a staging org more easily. Still need reverse engineering.