# use org session id for salesforce rest api call to get records

Tags: visualforce, rest, http

I'd like to make a rest api call from within my org.

From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm) "You can use a session ID instead of an OAuth 2.0 access token if you aren’t handling someone else’s password:"

in my VF page I use

```
<script>
    var restUrl = "https://" + window.location.hostname + "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Account/ -H " + "'Authorization: Bearer " + "{!$Api.Session_Id}'";
    console.log(restUrl);
</sript>
```

Shouldn't the value from `restUrl` be valid in doing a curl request or using an app like Postman to do HTTP requests?

Comment: You might want to check this document out on using forceTK to use javascript from visualforce: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/03/calling-the-rest-api-from-javascript-in-visualforce-pages.html

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? Copy that to a terminal to run in CURL?

Comment: @sfdcfox It works in CURL. I want to do a REST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe when you use `$Api.Session_Id` in Visualforce you get a different session than if you used UserInfo.getSessionId() from Apex.

See [$API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_api.htm)

> $Api.Session_ID and GETSESSIONID() return the same value, an identifier for the current session in the current context. This context varies depending on where the global variable or function is evaluated. For example, if you use either in a custom formula field, and that field is displayed on a standard page layout in Salesforce Classic, the referenced session will be a basic Salesforce session. That same field (or the underlying variable or formula result), when used in a Visualforce page, references a Visualforce session instead.

See [Different Session Ids in Different contexts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/23277/102)

From your example code, the likely problem is using `window.location.hostname` for the domain. If this is coming from a Visualforce page it will be wrong for the REST API.