# Session Id from Developer console and session Id from SOAPUI

Tags: soap, developer-console, session, session-id

I got session id from Developer console and as well as from SOAPUI at a time. But both are giving different session ids, but both the session ids are working properly.

What my questions are

a) Why these dev console and soapui are giving different session ids at a time.

b) Is there any difference between these session ids

Comment: A session ID is a unique number that a Web site's server assigns a specific user for the duration of that user's visit (session). Please check this link http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/session-ID

Comment: @SarojBera, Every time an Internet user visits a specific Web site, a new session ID is assigned. Closing a browser and then reopening and visiting the site again generates a new session ID. However, the same session ID is sometimes maintained as long as the browser is open, even if the user leaves the site in question and returns. In some cases, Web servers terminate a session and assign a new session ID after a few minutes of inactivity.
What i found in link provided by you. 
But here, we are using two types i.e, Dev console and soap....
i need it those context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [different "classes" of session](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/23277/102) that get provided in different contexts.

You get different types of Session primarily as a security control. Some can only be used to make API calls, some can't make API calls, while others give you the full level of control that the user has.

The Session Types are accessible under "User Session Information" in the setup pages. E.g.

[image]

They aren't particularly well documented as best I can tell. There is [Understanding Session Types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_session_types.htm&language=en_US&type=0), but it doesn't outline what the capabilities of each session type are. It also doesn't cover the corresponding Login Type column.

The Session ID that you could get from a SOAP UI login call would be a "full" session ID. The one from the developer console is usually fully functional, but is likely spun off as a child of the primary session. That would allow it to be killed off without terminating the primary session.

You can also get different types of session based on the scope if you are doing oAuth.

I do know that the Spring '17 Tooling API has not one, but two new SessionSettings complex types. One if the `sobject.tooling.soap.sforce.com` namespace and one in the `metadata.tooling.soap.sforce.com`. Both of those namespaces import the other. If that isn't enough to make your head explode you might be able to get some useful details out about the current session. Details like `securityCentralKillSession` and `enablePostForSessions`.