# Workaround for URL limit error of maximum 4096 characters when rendering VF page as PDF

Tags: visualforce, url, getcontentaspdf

I have a class `createPDF` which is called by a flow. When a new case is created the flow runs passes only Id of the case and this class recovers the necessary fields and creates a page reference to render a page with necessary fields as pdf and assigns the rendered pdf as attachment to the newly created case.

`createPDF`:

```
public without sharing class FlowCreatePDF {

    @InvocableMethod
    public static List<FlowOutput> checkCase(List<FlowInput> flowInputs) {
        List<FlowOutput> result = new List<FlowOutput>();

        try {
            for (FlowInput singleFlowInput: flowInputs) {
                FlowOutput singleResult = new FlowOutput();

                String caseId = singleFlowInput.caseId;
                System.debug('caseId -> '+ caseId);
                Case singleCase = [SELECT CaseNumber, Description, Type, Origin, ProtocolStructure__c, Account.Fiscal_Code__pc, Account.Name, ContactEmail, Street_Address__c, Number_Address__c, Letter_Address__c, Subject, Owner.Name, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name, LastModifiedBy.Name FROM Case WHERE Id =: caseId];
                //System.debug('singleCase -> '+ singleCase);

                String protocolStructure = String.isNotBlank(singleCase.ProtocolStructure__c) ? singleCase.ProtocolStructure__c:'';
                String caseName = String.isNotBlank(singleCase.Account?.Name) ? singleCase.Account.Name:'';
                String caseEmail = String.isNotBlank(singleCase.ContactEmail) ? singleCase.ContactEmail:'';
                String caseDescription = String.isNotBlank(singleCase.Description) ? singleCase.Description : '';


                Pagereference pg = Page.renderAsPdf;
                pg.getParameters().put('protocolStructure', protocolStructure);
                pg.getParameters().put('name', caseName);
                pg.getParameters().put('email', caseEmail);
                pg.getParameters().put('caseDescription ',  caseDescription);

                String pdfName = singleCase.CaseNumber + '-' + singleCase.Subject;

                ContentVersionService.createContentVersionFromPDF(pdfName, pdfName+'.pdf', pg.getContentAsPDF(), 'H', caseId, true);

                singleResult.isSuccess = true;
                result.add(singleResult);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //CATCH AND MANAGE ACCORDINGLY
        }
        return  result;
    }

    public class FlowInput {
        @InvocableVariable
        public String caseId;
    }

    public class FlowOutput {
        @InvocableVariable
        public Boolean isSuccess;

        @InvocableVariable
        public String errorMessage;
    }

}
```

The VF page has styling of page and fields. The controller class simply gets and sets fields for the page using `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('caseNumber');`

The problem is case description field is Long text area field with a limit of 32K characters, where as there is a limit of 4096 characters for URL. In fact I do get the error: `URL starting with ... is longer than the maximum allowed length of 4,096.` I need to get the page as a pdf and insert a new content version with the pdf assigned as version data to this content version, which is what I do in the method: `ContentVersionService.createContentVersionFromPDF(pdfName, pdfName+'.pdf', pg.getContentAsPDF(), caseId);`

I have read this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286898/how-to-get-past-the-url-limit-error-of-maximum-4096-characters), and if I am not mistaken it seems to me that I need to create the pdf as string with the html and css tags and pass them as request body, but if I am creating the pdf as string, I would not need make a `http` call as I can simply use `Blob.toPdf()`. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I'm confused. Why don't you just build an HTML string and call Blob.toPdf? Or, why don't you have the Visualforce page query any related Case data, instead of trying to generate a URL?

Comment: @sfdcfox Initially we only had few fields and didnt see the need to query the fields by vf page or use html string. But now we need to add the description field which is a long text area which can have up to 32K chars.
I get the Blob.toPdf idea but the part of "Visualforce page query any related Case data" do you mean calling the action method on the apex:page tag? But I am not actually loading the page i.e., no one will actually see the page, its meant only for creating a pdf.

Comment: Calling getContent or getContentAsPDF is loading the page. Just because it's not in a browser doesn't mean you can't query data automatically via standardController or manually via Apex. Sure, you don't get any JavaScript support, which doesn't matter, since you're rendering a PDF, but the Apex and Visualforce will work just as you'd expect. Alternatively, Blob.toPDF does work, but it's more limited in functionality for some reason.

Comment: The only downside is that Visualforce generation counts as a callout and happens in a separate transaction, which means it may not be able to see the related data directly. You might want to move this logic to asynchronous code (e.g. future) to avoid this problem.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you, resolved by passing only the case id using getParameters().put('caseId', caseId); and querying and setting the required fields in VF Controller constructor.